# Arithmetic operation like Add for a Generic List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda, expression

Doing Add for two elements like `T a, T b` is simple, Mark has provided a good solution using Expression tree [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/genericoperators.html), which translates into following and is simple to use:

```
static T Add<T>(T a, T b)
{
    // Declare Parameter Expressions
    ParameterExpression paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "valueA"),
        paramB = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "valueB");

    // add the parameters together
    BinaryExpression body = Expression.Add(paramA, paramB);

    // Compile it
    Func<T, T, T> add = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(body, paramA, paramB).Compile();

    // Call it
    return add(a, b);
}
```

Challenge that I have is there's a collection of `List<T>`, where all elements have to added as shown above. I have tried following, on same lines as above, but it doesn't work:

```
static T AddAll<T>(List<T> list)
{
    var parameterExpressionList = list.Select((x,i) => (Expression)Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "value"+i));

    var body =  parameterExpressionList
                                  .Skip(1)
                                  .Aggregate(parameterExpressionList.First(), 
                                   (paramA, paramB) => Expression.Add(paramA, paramB));

    // Compile it
    Func<List<T>, T> addAll = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, T>>(body, parameterExpressionList.Cast<ParameterExpression>()).Compile();

    return addAll(list);
}
```

Run-time error that I get is: **Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration**. Any pointer, how to achieve, please note, I don't need a solution where I cumulatively pick two elements from actual list and call `Add<T>(T a, T b)` , since that would lead to multiple times compilation of the Expression tree, which is not efficient, as I would have > 100 K data points, any suggestion to make my code work would be great, I am not sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: You want to add (sum) all the numbers in a list together?

Comment: yes and the type is known at run-time, though numeric can be int, double, long, decimal

Comment: `List<T>().Sum()`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj there is a LINQ extension method called `.Sum()` as Sam mentioned.  example: `int sum = someList.Sum(x => x.SomeInteger);`

Comment: My implementation is Generic, where Type is known at run-time, so this would not work. Essentially List<T>.Sum() is not valid, as type is not known, currently I do for each type and it has lead to bloated code

Comment: Are you sure that you know type at runtime but compile-time?

Comment: Yes since it knows the types at run-time using reflection, I am not calling it using type at compile time

Comment: Actually, your example uses types at compile time, as generic types are set at compile time. The only real way to handle this with runtime types is using `dynamic`.

Comment: You get this error because you have declared *a list of parameters* in `parameterExpressionList ` but `Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, T>>` expects **one** parameter of type list

Comment: Benchmark results of adding 100000 integers: NetMage 2.17ms, Andrés Robinet: 2.46ms, tinudu: 1.12ms, George Alexandria, nejs: stack overflow, loopedcode: N/A

Comment: @tinudu, can you try with a bigger set, like a million? Also, can you check my comment to replace `Aggregate` with a regular foreach loop? I can do benchmarking but I'm feeling a bit lazy :) (maybe I try later). If you'd be so kind to take my suggestion I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: I did (but deleted the test code meanwhile). It remains about the same ratio. The bigger the set, the less expression building/compiling or dynamic invocation have an impact. The dominant effect becomes invoking a delegate vs executing a processor instruction for each item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have created a generic function, just use it on the list (I added an optional Adder method to handle non-standard classes):

```
static T AddAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, T, T> adder = null) {
    // Declare Parameter Expressions
    ParameterExpression paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "valueA"),
        paramB = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "valueB");

    // add the parameters together
    BinaryExpression body;
    if (adder == null)
        body = Expression.Add(paramA, paramB);
    else
        body = Expression.Add(paramA, paramB, adder.GetMethodInfo());

    // Compile it
    Func<T, T, T> add = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(body, paramA, paramB).Compile();

    // Call it
    return src.Aggregate(default(T), (ans, n) => add(ans, n));
}
```

You can use the `Adder` parameter to handle things like `strings`:

```
var ans = AddAll(new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, String.Concat);
```

Since we know the type of `T` at compile time though, we can just call `Sum`:

```
static T AddAll2<T>(IEnumerable<T> src) {
    var paramA = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "valueA");

    var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Sum", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>) });
    if (method != null) {
        // Create lambda body
        var body = Expression.Call(method, paramA);

        // Compile it
        Func<IEnumerable<T>, T> sum = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<T>, T>>(body, paramA).Compile();

        // Call it
        return sum(src);
    }
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

Of course, if you are going to call `Sum`, you don't need a lambda:

```
static T AddAll3<T>(IEnumerable<T> src) {
    var method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Sum", new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>) });
    if (method != null) {
        // Call it
        return (T)method.Invoke(null, new[] { src });
    }
    else
        return default(T);
}
```

Comment: `src.Aggregate(default(T), add)` would not throw in case of an empty sequence.

Comment: Best solution (besides of my own, of course ;-) ) so far, as it builds and compiles a tiny expression only, and enumerates `src` instead of indexing into it (or worse: accessing it at run time an wrap it into a constant expression). Consider using `IEnumerable<T>` for the parameter instead of `List<T>` to gain generality.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I was concerned that `default(T)` might not work for some user defined classes but I guess they could just have `Add` defined to handle `null` properly.

Comment: Though other solutions are also good but AddAll is closest to what I need, since in a single pass I need to also do evaluation of Min, Max, Average. I can in this case use a single enumeration to do the same, other solutions rely on invoking inbuilt methods like "Sum", which would need multiple enumerations for complete result

Answer (score 1):

Just try to get every item from your list and then accumulate they into result.

```
    static T AddAll<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        if (list.Count == 0)
        {
            // It's additional small case
            return default(T);
        }

        var listParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<T>));

        var propInfo = typeof(List<T>).GetProperty("Item");
        var indexes = list.Select((x, i) => Expression.MakeIndex(listParam, propInfo, new[] { Expression.Constant(i) }));

        Expression sum = indexes.First();
        foreach (var item in indexes.Skip(1))
        {
            sum = Expression.Add(sum, item);
        }

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, T>>(sum, listParam).Compile();
        return lambda(list);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass list directly as argument and just create sum via indexes:

```
static T AddAll<T>(List<T> list)
{
    if (list.Count == 0) return default(T);
    if (list.Count == 1) return list[0];

    var indexerProperty = typeof(List<T>).GetProperty("Item");

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<T>));
    var exp = Expression.Add(
        Expression.MakeIndex(p, indexerProperty, new [] { Expression.Constant(0) }),
        Expression.MakeIndex(p, indexerProperty, new [] { Expression.Constant(1) }));
    for (var i = 2; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        exp = Expression.Add(
            exp,
            Expression.MakeIndex(p, indexerProperty, new [] { Expression.Constant(i) }));
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<T>, T>>(exp, p).Compile();
    return lambda(list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, using the similar logic is it possible to figure out Max and Min too, as they would be of type `Func<T,T,bool>` instead of `Func<T,T,T>` for Sum

Answer (score 1):

Store all applicable `Enumerable.Sum` overloads in a dictionary:

```
// all methods with signature public static T Enumerable.Sum(IEnumerable<T>) by element type
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> _sumMethodsByElementType = typeof(Enumerable)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Sum" && !m.IsGenericMethod)
    .Select(m => new { Method = m, Parameters = m.GetParameters() })
    .Where(mp => mp.Parameters.Length == 1)
    .Select(mp => new { mp.Method, mp.Parameters[0].ParameterType })
    .Where(mp => mp.ParameterType.IsGenericType && mp.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
    .Select(mp => new { mp.Method, ElementType = mp.ParameterType.GetGenericArguments()[0] })
    .Where(me => me.Method.ReturnType == me.ElementType)
    .ToDictionary(mp => mp.ElementType, mp => mp.Method);
```

Invoke the corresponding one from inside the generic `AddAll` (or `Sum` as I prefer to call it) method:

```
public static T Sum<T>(IEnumerable<T> summands)
{
    MethodInfo sumMethod;
    if (!_sumMethodsByElementType.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out sumMethod)) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot sum elements of type {typeof(T)}.");

    return (T)sumMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { summands });
}
```

Test:

```
Console.WriteLine(Sum(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
Console.WriteLine(Sum(new[] { 1, 2, 3, default(int?) }));
Console.WriteLine(Sum(new[] { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3 }));
Console.WriteLine(Sum(new[] { 1.1, 2.2, 3.3, default(double?) }));

try { Console.WriteLine(Sum(new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' })); }
catch (InvalidOperationException ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }
```

Output:

```
6
6
6.6
6.6
Cannot sum elements of type System.Char.
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to solve every part of the problem with expressions, if you are just interested in the operation itself

Here's an implementation that uses `Singleton` via the `Lazy<>` type for the default addition of type `T` (instead of static methods)

The `LinqExpression` expression could potentially be reused if you **really** need expressions (say, in an EF scenario), but there's no equivalent expression for the `AddAll` operation... though it can potentially be expanded to support a *generic expression* for `AddAll`

```
public abstract class Addition<T>
{
    private readonly Lazy<Expression<Func<T, T, T>>> _lazyExpression;
    private readonly Lazy<Func<T, T, T>> _lazyFunc;

    public Func<T, T, T> Execute
    {
        get { return _lazyFunc.Value; }
    }

    public Expression<Func<T, T, T>> LinqExpression
    {
        get { return _lazyExpression.Value; }
    }

    protected Addition()
    {
        _lazyExpression = new Lazy<Expression<Func<T, T, T>>>(InitializeExpression);
        _lazyFunc = new Lazy<Func<T, T, T>>(() => LinqExpression.Compile());
    }

    protected abstract Expression<Func<T, T, T>> InitializeExpression();
}

public sealed class DefaultAddition<T> : Addition<T>
{
    private static readonly Lazy<DefaultAddition<T>> _lazyInstance = new Lazy<DefaultAddition<T>>(() => new DefaultAddition<T>());

    public static DefaultAddition<T> Instance
    {
        get {return _lazyInstance.Value; }
    }

    // Private constructor, you only get an instance via the Instance static property
    private DefaultAddition()
    {
    }

    protected override Expression<Func<T, T, T>> InitializeExpression()
    {
        var paramX = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        var paramY = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "y");
        var body = Expression.Add(paramX, paramY);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(body, paramX, paramY);
    }
}

public static class Operations
{
    public static T Add<T>(T x, T y)
    {
        return DefaultAddition<T>.Instance.Execute(x, y);
    }

    public static T AddAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        var itemAdd = DefaultAddition<T>.Instance.Execute;
        return enumerable.Aggregate(default(T), (result, item) => itemAdd(result, item));

        // This might be more efficient than Aggregate, but I didn't benchmark it

        /*
        var result = default(T);
        foreach (var item in enumerable)
        {
            result = itemAdd(result, item);
        }
        return result;
        */
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// Can mix double with int :)
var doubleAdd = Operations.Add(4.5, 3);

// Can mix decimal with int :)
var listAdd = Operations.AddAll(new[] {3, 6.7m, 0.3m});

// Even empty enumerables
var shortAdd = Operations.AddAll(Enumerable.Empty<short>());

// This will not work for byte. System.Byte should be casted to System.Int32
// Throws "InvalidOperationException: The binary operator Add is not defined for the types 'System.Byte' and 'System.Byte'."
var byteAdd = Operations.AddAll(new byte[] {1, 2, 3});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your T is of value type like int, long, double etc. then you can simply do this:

```
//add
//using System.Linq;

var items = new List<int>();
items.Add(1);
items.Add(5);
items.Add(10);

var sum = items.Sum();
```

Comment: Please check my question again I need a generic code, which can work for multiple types, I already have separate implementation for various types. Only Expression tree can solve this, not using the Linq APIs

Comment: Please remove this answer, as its incorrect and someone may down vote. Linq Sum() is not my requirement